# Verilog 2's complement adder/subtraction

Tags: verilog

design 8-bit adder-subtractor using Verilog.

op=0 --> A+B (add)

op=1 --> A-B (subtract)

i tried to do -87-(-116)=29

I insert testbench   #10 A=-8'b10101001; B=-8'b10001100; op=1;

However, Verilog is Negative recognition failed.
And Originally result should print 00011101, but result print wrong value 1110 0011

How can i fix this problem?

Below is my code

```
module addsub8 ( A ,B ,mode ,result ,overflow );

output [7:0] result ;
wire [7:0] result ;
output overflow ;
wire overflow ;

input   [7:0] A ;
wire   [7:0] A ;
input    [7:0] B ;
wire   [7:0] B ;
input mode ;
wire mode ;

//}} End of automatically maintained section

// -- Enter your statements here -- //

wire B0; 
wire B1; 
wire B2; 
wire B3; 
wire B4; 
wire B5; 
wire B6; 
wire B7; 

wire C0; 
wire C1; 
wire C2; 
wire C3;
wire C4; 
wire C5; 
wire C6; 
wire C7;  

xor(B0, B[0], mode);
xor(B1, B[1], mode);
xor(B2, B[2], mode);
xor(B3, B[3], mode);
xor(B4, B[4], mode);
xor(B5, B[5], mode);
xor(B6, B[6], mode);
xor(B7, B[7], mode);


fa U0(A[0],B0,mode,C0,result[0]);
fa U1(A[1],B1,C0,C1,result[1]);
fa U2(A[2],B2,C1,C2,result[2]);
fa U3(A[3],B3,C2,C3,result[3]);
fa U4(A[4],B4,C3,C4,result[4]);
fa U5(A[5],B5,C4,C5,result[5]);
fa U6(A[6],B6,C5,C6,result[6]);
fa U7(A[7],B7,C6,C7,result[7]);  

xor (overflow,C6,C7);                

endmodule


module fa ( A ,B ,Cin ,Cout ,S );

output Cout ;
output  S ;           


input A ;
wire A ;
input B ;
wire B ;
input Cin ;
wire Cin ;    

reg Cout;
reg S;


//}} End of automatically maintained section

// -- Enter your statements here -- //

always @(A or B or Cin) begin
    case ({A,B,Cin})
     0: begin Cout=0; S=0; end
     1: begin Cout=0; S=1; end
     2: begin Cout=0; S=1; end      
     3: begin Cout=1; S=0; end
     4: begin Cout=0; S=1; end
     5: begin Cout=1; S=0; end
     6: begin Cout=1; S=0; end
     7: begin Cout=1; S=1; end
    endcase
    end

endmodule
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your comment 'Verilog Negative recognition failed' When doing twos complement it is only you that has the concept of negative. Verilog simulation is just applying boolean logic to bits.

Comment: That is part's of the Verilog testbench code

Comment: Even though the result is positive, It is output as 2's complement.

Comment: add not working too

Comment: can you see edited my question?      B0...7 value is not problem

Comment: Is this a verilog exercise (RTL) or a gate level exercise?

Answer (score 1):

1/ If you wan to work with negative numbers like -A and if you want 8'b10101001 to be seen as a negative number use signed vectors:

```
input  signed [7:0] A ;
wire   signed [7:0] A ;
```

I quickly scanned your code and I see only standard (unsigned) vectors.

2/ Do not mess about with one bit full adders, just use the language:

```
assign R = A + B;
```

Comment: input  signed [7:0] A ;
wire   signed [7:0] A ;           I tried this But, result is There is still a problem.     and what's the mean about this code?  assign R = A + B;

Comment: It means add and subtract vectors. Not bits. And you have to make **all** signals signed! I can write the whole solution in about 4-5 lines of code, including module definition and endmodule.

Comment: I had assumed it was a gate level exercise being written that way.

Comment: @Morgan Work though Verilog and VHDL posts a few months. You will not believe what you encounter. ~30% are plain syntax errors which people can't find. ~40% are about blocking vs non-blocking, ~15% are code written like C ('how do I call a module'). ~13% are weird loops which are not static. ~2% are good questions. I would love to write a pages where people are referred to with every HDL question saying: Check these rules. If you break any of them correct and comes back if it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine for me in EDA Playground https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5dRL

I guess that your issue is that you check the result immediately and do not allow any time for the result to propagate.

ie

```
#10 A=-8'd87; B=8'b116; op=0;
Check answer
```

allowing at least 1 time step allows a combinatorial answer to propagate:

```
#10 A=-8'd87; B=8'b116; op=0;
#1;
Check answer
```